# Powershell [Environment] inconsistencies

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I am trying to be consistent in my code, using either `$env:` or `[Environment]`, but not a mix. However, I am seeing some inconsistencies in what seems to be implemented.
So `[Environment]::UserName` and `$env:userName` both work fine. `$env:computerName` works, but `[Environment]::COMPUTERNAME` doesn't. Oddly `[Environment]::MachineName` does, despite the fact that `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables()` says `[Environment]::COMPUTERNAME` is present, not `[Environment]::MachineName`. Also, `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables()` says `[Environment]::USERPROFILE` should work, but it actually returns nothing.
When I look at the Microsoft doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment?view=net-5.0) about properties of the `[Environment]` type I do see `MachineName`, along with `UserName`, and no mention of `UserProfile`. So, obviously that IS the right resource. But that begs the question, why does `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables()` return such inconsistent information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Environment]` or more specifically `[System.Environment]` is restricted to the static methods and properties documented at the link you provided.

`[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables` returns a list of environment variables and their values, some of which the operating system sets for you (`"COMPUTERNAME"`, `"USERNAME"`, etc.) which do overlap with some of the `[Environment]` properties, but also include any environment variables applications have added or users have added typically using System Properties / Advanced / Environment Variables.

`[Environment]::USERPROFILE` doesn't return anything because `USERPROFILE` isn't a static property on the `[System.Environment]` class.  You can list all the static properties like this:

```ps
    [System.Environment] | Get-Member -MemberType Properties -Static
```

You can add new environment variables that will then be returned using `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariables`.  For example:

```ps
    $env:TEST = "This is a test"
```

[image: For example:]

More good info and examples of environment variables (not the `[Environment]` class) here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1